# nodeJs - can't acces required properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 separate files - the main script file and config.js located in the same folder.

I then require the config.js as a variable, and try to access it's url property, but somehow it does not get injected properly. What am I doing wrong?

If I define a local variable with the url, and pass it into my function everything works as expected.

main.js:

```
//import configuration
var config = ("./config.js");

casper.start(config.url);
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'http://stage2.btobet.net/en',
    credentials: [{ user: 'Tester', password: '' },
        { user: 'Automat', password: '' }]
};
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to write require

```
var config = require("./config.js");
```